# Prove the following properties of given semigroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, finite-groups, semigroups

> Let ({a,b},*) be a semigroup where $ a * a  = b$. Show that:
>   (a) $ a*b=b*a$
>   (b) $b*b=b$

I've managed to prove the (a) part as: $$ a * b = a * ( a * a ) = (a * a) * a = b * a $$ But for the (b) part all I could work out was that if: $$ a * b = a = b * a $$ then 
$$\begin{align*}
b*b&=(a*a)*(a*a)\\
  &=(a*(a*b))*(a*a)\\
  &=(b*b)*(a*a)\\
  &=(b*a)*(b*a)\\
  &=a*a=b 
\end{align*}$$ 
But I couldn't find a way to constructively find why $b*b = b$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a*b \ne a$, then $a*b=b$ and $b*b=a*a*b=a*b=b$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The hint:

If $ab=b$ then $a^2=b^2=ab=ba=b$.

If $ab=a$ we get $b^2=b$ again.

Comment: Thank you for helping.